# How to update Android UI on Firestore result?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a database query in Cloud Firestore in Kotlin.

The request itself is working but I am having some problems with the async workflow.

My goal is to make a database request that fetches a lot of data and puts this into an object.
Once this is complete for all objects, the normal workflow of the app should continue. (because I need to display some of this data in my UI).

My database structure:
I have a collection of users
-> Each user has a collection of their own recipes.
-> In each recipe there is a collection of Steps to complete and a collection of ingredients

My goal is to get the data and show it on my app screen (code below), but with my current code, the app starts the request and continues to show the app screen (which means there is no data loaded up to this point).

Is there a way to make my database request more efficient (as I have 3 requests per recipe) and also to make it work async? So that when the data gets loaded the UI will recognize a change and show this to the UI later on or the UI waits till all the requests are complete?

Sorry if this is a basic question about coroutines, but I am pretty new to this topic and could not find any info in the Firebase documentation.

My Code:

in My Main Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        loadRecipes()//should load the information from the Database
        initUiElements()//should show the Information in a Recycler View
    }
```

-> load Recipies calls the following Class with the loadloadRecipes() function

Class: FirebaseRecipes:

```
fun loadRecipes(){

        //First DB Request to get the Recipe Names and Durations
        Log.d("FirebaseRecipes", "loadRecipes()")
        db.collection("users").document(userID.toString()).collection("Recipes").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    val duration = document.data["duration"].toString()
                    val name = document.data["name"].toString()
                    var recipe = Recipe(name, duration)
                    RecipesList.add(recipe)

                    //Second DB Request to get the Ingredients
                    db.collection("users").document(userID.toString()).collection("Recipes").document(document.id).collection("ingredients").get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                            for (document in result) {
                                val amount = document.data["amount"].toString()
                                val name = document.data["name"].toString()
                                val barcode = document.data["unit"].toString()
                                val ingredient = Ingredient(name, amount, barcode)
                                recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
                            }
                        }

                    //Third DB Request to get the Steps
                 db.collection("users").document(userID.toString()).collection("Recipes").document(document.id).collection("steps").get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                            for (document in result) {
                                val step = document.data["text"].toString()
                                recipe.steps.add(step)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
    }
```

**Solution:**

with the answers of @AlexMamo, @UsmanMahmood and @NguyễnMinhKhoa I was able to get the following solution to my problem:

I Created a ViewModel that contains my List:

```
private val _recipeList =
        MutableLiveData<CustomResponse<List<Recipe>>>(CustomResponse.Loading())
    val recipeList: LiveData<CustomResponse<List<Recipe>>>
        get() = _recipeList

    fun shareRecipe(recipes: List<Recipe>) {
        _recipeList.value = CustomResponse.Success(recipes)
    }
```

in the class that should retrieve the data from Firebase I created the following function, to retrieve the data and store it to the View Model:

```
fun loadRecipes(activity: Activity) {
        val model =
            ViewModelProvider(activity as ViewModelStoreOwner)[ViewModel::class.java]

        db.collection("users").document(userID.toString()).collection("Recipes").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                val recipesList = ArrayList<Recipe>()
                for (document in result) {
                    val duration = document.data["duration"].toString()
                    val name = document.data["name"].toString()
                    var recipe = Recipe(name, duration)
                    recipesList.add(recipe)

                    recipe.steps = document.data["steps"] as ArrayList<String>

                    val ingredients =
                        document.data["ingredients"] as ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>
                    for (ingredient in ingredients) {
                        val name = ingredient["name"].toString()
                        val amount = (ingredient["amount"] as Long).toInt()
                        val ingredient = Ingredient(name, amount)
                        recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
                    }
                    model.shareRecipe(recipesList)
                }
            }
    }
```

A Custom Response:

```
sealed class CustomResponse<T>(val  data: T? = null, val errorMessage:String? =null) {                                    ;
    class Loading<T> : CustomResponse<T>()
    class Success<T>(data: T? = null) : CustomResponse<T>(data = data)
    class Error<T>(errorMessage: String) : CustomResponse<T>(errorMessage = errorMessage)
}
```

and in the fragments I can call it like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val model = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[RecipesViewModel::class.java]
model.recipeList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
            when (response as CustomResponse<List<Recipe>>) {
                is CustomResponse.Loading -> {
                    rvRecipes.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                is CustomResponse.Success -> {
                    rvRecipes.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

                    Log.d("FirebaseRecipes", "Recipes loaded within Fragment")

                    adapter.content = response.data as ArrayList<Recipe>
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                is CustomResponse.Error -> {
                    response.errorMessage?.let {
                        rvRecipes.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        //TODO: Display error message
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? More efficient in terms of what? What is exactly is not efficient now?

Comment: @AlexMamo In my case, I receive several recipes. if I wait to retrieve the data for each one, I get enormous load times. but if I could retrieve all the recipes in parallel, I would probably save a lot of time.

Comment: To understand better. Do you need to get the ingredients and the steps of all users at the same time? And you want to perform al requests in parallel?

Comment: @AlexMamo No, I want all the recipes for one user. 
And the recipes must have the ingredients and the steps. 
So it would be optimal to get the information for all the recipes in parallel.

The second question is, how can I update the UI when I have received all the information?

Comment: What is the maximum number of recipes a user can have? And what is the maximum number of ingredients a recipe can have? And what is the maximum number of steps a recipe can have?

Comment: @AlexMamo till now there are no limits about the size of these collections

Comment: Ok, I understand but it can be a maximum. It really depends on these numbers. According to your answer, I will provide the answer accordingly.

Comment: @AlexMamo the base limit in Firebase seems to be 100 items within a collection, so I would go for that

Comment: Aside from my answer, or reading a single document, or multiple documents, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Live Data for that and manage state using Custom Response to Manage Success, Loading and error state when the data is loading show loader in UI you have to do something like this

```
  private val _recipeList = MutableLiveData<CustomResponse<List<Recipe>>>(CustomResponse.Loading())
val recipeList: LiveData<CustomResponse<List<Recipe>>>
    get() = _recipeList
```

In the function set value of _recipeList:

```
 for (document in result) {
                val duration = document.data["duration"].toString()
                val name = document.data["name"].toString()
                var recipe = Recipe(name, duration)
                RecipesList.add(recipe)

                //Second DB Request to get the Ingredients
                db.collection("users").document(userID.toString()).collection("Recipes").document(document.id).collection("ingredients").get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                        for (document in result) {
                            val amount = document.data["amount"].toString()
                            val name = document.data["name"].toString()
                            val barcode = document.data["unit"].toString()
                            val ingredient = Ingredient(name, amount, barcode)
                            recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
                        }
                    }

                //Third DB Request to get the Steps
             db.collection("users").document(userID.toString()).collection("Recipes").document(document.id).collection("steps").get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                        for (document in result) {
                            val step = document.data["text"].toString()
                            recipe.steps.add(step)
                        }
                    }
            }
 _recipeList.value = CustomResponse.Success(RecipeList)
```

and in activity/fragment do something like this :

```
recipeList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
            when (response) {
                is CustomResponse.Loading -> {
                    binding.recylerViewReicepes.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                is CustomResponse.Success -> {recipeList ->
                    binding.recylerViewReicepes.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    adapter.setList(recipeList)
                 
  
                    }
                }
```

Here is the CustomResoponse sealed class :

```
 sealed class CustomResponse<T>(val  data: T? = null, val errorMessage:String? =null)
{                                    ;
    class Loading<T> : CustomResponse<T>()
    class Success<T>(data: T? = null) : CustomResponse<T>(data = data)
    class Error<T>(errorMessage: String) : CustomResponse<T>(errorMessage = errorMessage)
}
```

And if the recipes list is too big which can cause user to wait for several minutes then you can set _reicpesList at the end of for loop this will improve user experience so that user don't have to wait until all the recipes are loaded

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this later today, this seems to be a great solution to the problem of loading times.

Comment: In Android development with Kotlin, LiveData isn't used anymore. We use Kotlin Coroutines and Flow.

Answer (score 0):

> The base limit in Firebase seems to be 100 items within a collection

There is no such limitation in Firestore. You can add as many documents as you want in a collection, even billions.

> I want all the recipes for one user.

So if you think that the maximum number of recipes a user can have is 100, then you can add all of them in a single document, including the ingredients and the steps. In this way, you'll have to pay for a single-read operation. However, there is a limitation when it comes to how much data you can store in a single document. You can only store data [up to 1 MiB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits).

If you think that you can get over this limitation, which I doubt, then instead of creating one document, you might consider creating two, or even three. So there is no need in this case to create a separate document for each recipe, ingredient, and step. All the data cand be stored as object in an array.

Comment: Hey Pantastix. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: That is a great idea, I will definitely look into it later today. I completely overlooked the idea of using an array for this.